# Как передать параметры в функцию используя SLOT, чтоб сформировать запрос на добавление в базу записи?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

У меня автоматически генерируются Line Edit и Label? В зависимости от того какие колонки в таблицах SQLite. Но как мне автоматически передавать нужные параметры для формирования запроса на добавления записи в таблицу SQLite?

```
connect(ButtonAdd,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(AddNote(TableName,ColumnName)));

void MainWindow::AddNote (TableName,ColumnName) {
    Login conn;
    conn.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery query;
    QString sqlQueryAddNote = QString("insert into %1 (%2) values (").arg(TableName).arg(ColumnName.join(","));
    for (int i=0; i<ColumnName.size(); i++) {
        sqlQueryAddNote +=QString("'+LineEditColumn[i]->text()+',");
    }
    query.prepare(sqlQueryAddNote);
    query.exec();
    conn.connClose();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "login.h"
#include <QTableView>
#include <qspinbox.h>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Login conn;
    conn.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery* queryTablesAll = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
    QString sqlQueryTablesAll = QString("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type ='table'");
    queryTablesAll->prepare(sqlQueryTablesAll);
    queryTablesAll->exec();

    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout=new QVBoxLayout;
    ui->centralWidget_2->setLayout(mainLayout);
    QTabWidget* Tab = new QTabWidget(this);
    mainLayout->addWidget(Tab);
    int count = 1;
    while (queryTablesAll->next()) {
             QGroupBox *formGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("%1").arg(queryTablesAll->value(0).toString()));
             QGridLayout* Layout = new QGridLayout;

             if(queryTablesAll->value(0).toString() != "sqlite_sequence") {
                Tab->addTab(formGroupBox,queryTablesAll->value(0).toString());

                QSqlQueryModel *modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
                QSqlQuery* queryTable = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
                QString sqlQueryTable = QString("SELECT * FROM %1").arg(queryTablesAll->value(0).toString());
                queryTable->prepare(sqlQueryTable);
                queryTable->exec();

                QSqlRecord recordTable = queryTable->record();
                QLabel *labelsColumn[recordTable.count()];
                QLineEdit *LineEditColumn[recordTable.count()];

                for(int i=0; i<recordTable.count(); i++) {
                    labelsColumn[i] = new QLabel(tr("Line %1:").arg(i + 1));
                    labelsColumn[i]->setText(recordTable.fieldName(i));

                    QSqlField fieldTable = recordTable.field(i);
                    if (fieldTable.type()== QVariant::String) {
                       LineEditColumn[i] = new QLineEdit;
                       if (recordTable.fieldName(i) == "дата"
                        || recordTable.fieldName(i) == "Дата"
                        || recordTable.fieldName(i) == "ДАТА" ) {
                        LineEditColumn[i]->setText(QDate::currentDate().toString());
                       } else if (recordTable.fieldName(i) == "время"
                               || recordTable.fieldName(i) == "Время"
                               || recordTable.fieldName(i) == "ВРЕМЯ" ) {
                         LineEditColumn[i]->setText(QTime::currentTime().toString());
                       }
                       LineEditColumn[i]->setMaximumWidth(300);
                       //Layout->addRow(labelsColumn[i],LineEditColumn[i]);
                       Layout->addWidget(labelsColumn[i], i + 1, 0);
                       Layout->addWidget(LineEditColumn[i], i + 1, 1);
                    } else if (fieldTable.type()== QVariant::Int) {

                    }
                    //QStringList ColumnName;
                    ColumnName.append(recordTable.fieldName(i));
                }
                QPushButton *ButtonAdd = new QPushButton(tr("Добавить запись в %1").arg(queryTablesAll->value(0).toString()), this);
                Layout->addWidget(ButtonAdd,recordTable.count()+1,0,1,2);
                modal->setQuery(*queryTable);
                QTableView *TableView = new QTableView(this);
                TableView->setModel(modal);
                Layout->addWidget(TableView, 0, 2, recordTable.count()+2, 1);
                formGroupBox->setLayout(Layout);
                //QString TableName;
                TableName = queryTablesAll->value(0).toString();
                connect(ButtonAdd,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(AddNote()));
                count++;
             }
    }
    conn.connClose();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::AddNote () {
    qDebug()<<TableName;
    for (int i;i<ColumnName.size();i++){
        qDebug()<<ColumnName.value(i);
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Q_SLOT void AddNote ();
    QString TableName;
    QStringList ColumnName;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помог Урок [Динамическое создание виджетов в Qt](https://evileg.com/ru/post/77/). Я создал QDynamicButton и передал параметры в конструктор QDynamicButton: `QDynamicButton *buttonAdd = new QDynamicButton(this,TableName,ColumnName,ListLineEdit,ListTableView);`. Так мне удалось добавить запись в нужную таблицу по нажатию определённой кнопки. `QList<QLineEdit*> _ListLineEdit;` помог передать именно те `QLineEdit`, в которые я вводил данные на запись.

Answer (score 1):

В слот параметры передаются только из сигнала, к сожалению.

Но есть возможность указать в качестве слота лямбда-функцию и уже в ней передать нужные параметры. Например:

```
connect(ButtonAdd, &QAbstractButton::clicked, [&](bool)
{
     this->AddNote("table", {"field1","field2"});
});
```

Эта техника хорошо работает когда, у вас и таблицы и колонки заранее известны на момент разработки.

У вас же, судя по тому что я вижу, другой случай, у вас элементы создаются во время исполнения. В таком случае нужно в слоте получать нужные параметры, то есть в слоте вы должны как-то "знать" какие поля добавлять. Тут нужно либо иметь отдельные слоты на каждую кнопку, либо иметь один слот где обрабатываются все кнопки. Обрабатывать кнопки можно с помощью функции [QObject::sender](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) которая возвращает указатель на отправителя сигнала, то есть для вашего примера она вернет `ButtonAdd` если нажмется эта кнопка.